# Is this "modern" message box UI available in Qt? Or is it pure Windows API?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mfc

Modern Windows versions (I would say 7+) have this nice UI that I see often:

[image]

It doesn't seem like it was designed from scratch. It seems to me that it's already available in the Windows API.

**Is it possible to load this in Qt? What's the widget name? Or is it just MFC or something?**

Comment: This is a [TaskDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471(v=vs.85).aspx), so pure WinAPI but I guess there is a QT wrapper.

Comment: @zett42 Oh, thanks a lot. Actually that answers the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three buttons are called Command Buttons or [Command Link Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742403(v=vs.85).aspx). It was first introduced as part of the Windows XP API. The form in the picture (with explaining text under the command link) is available since Windows Vista, I think.

If you want portable code, you can't use it in Qt. Not even Wine can display command buttons by now. (In Wine 2.0 they are invisible but they can be klicked).

Update: There is a [QCommandLinkButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcommandlinkbutton.html) class in Qt.

Answer (score 3):

This is called a [TaskDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471(v=vs.85).aspx) which is available beginning with Windows Vista. It is pure Win API.

I don't know if there is a Qt wrapper available (**Edit**: [@thomiels answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43275743/7571258) links to a Qt widget).

Here is some native code to create a dialog similar to the one shown in the screenshot:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    TASKDIALOGCONFIG cfg{ sizeof(cfg) };
    const TASKDIALOG_BUTTON buttons[] = {
        { IDOK, L"Do something" },
        { IDCANCEL, L"Do another something" },
    };
    cfg.hInstance                    = ::GetModuleHandle( nullptr );
    cfg.dwCommonButtons              = 0;
    cfg.pszMainIcon                  = TD_INFORMATION_ICON;
    cfg.pszMainInstruction           = L"Here you can do awesome stuff";
    cfg.pszContent                   = L"What do you want to do?";
    cfg.pButtons                     = buttons;
    cfg.cButtons                     = ARRAYSIZE(buttons);
    cfg.dwFlags                      = TDF_USE_COMMAND_LINKS;

    HRESULT hr = TaskDialogIndirect( &cfg, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a Task Dialog. There seems to be too many elements missing. More likely it's a custom-made dialog using Command Links.

Comment: @thomiel It's indeed possible to create a dialog as shown in OP's screenshot. It's just a matter of using the right parameters. I've added a sample that does that.

Comment: @thomiel: There is no indication that this weren't a Task Dialog. From [About Task Dialogs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760441.aspx): *"A task dialog consists of several elements, **most of which are optional**."* You can strip down a Task Dialog to look like the dialog posted in the question.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong and WinZip actually uses the Task Dialog. But the the quantum physicist asked, if it's possible to have it in Qt. Providing the code doesn't help him. But thanks zett42 for mentioning the Task Dialog! I wasn't aware this existed.

Comment: I totally agree. @TheQuantumPhysicist should accept your answer as it actually shows a way to create a dialog like this in Qt.